# Improve speed of distance calculation

Tags: r

I have a problem like this. I want to find out distance between strings of words and place result in the data frame to compare distances:

```
a = c("aaa", "baab", "cddaa", "ddeeaaf")

library(stringdist)

string = stringdistmatrix(a, a, method =  "lv", useNames = "string")
res = expand.grid(a, a)
res$score <- mapply(function(x,y) string[x,y], res[,1], res[,2])
```

Code runs good, but it takes long time when there are many rows in "a". How I can make this run faster? Is there ways to increase speed of ditance calculation and optimize?

Comment: `stringdistmatrix()` is optimized and runs in parallel by default.  Any slow down is in your use of `mapply()` which with `expand.grid()` is unnecessary.  Just use `as.data.frame.table(stringdistmatrix(a, a, method =  "lv", useNames = "string"), responseName = "score")`.

Comment: Also often we are not interested in the string difference of all, but just on "close" matches.  It can help especially on long strings (think of duplicate/copied texts) to take the char length and avoid the expensive distance calculation between "this is a long string we want to check" comparing with "short text" and based on the big difference in char length you can conclude a distance calculation is not needed.